# redirecting a dynamic url containing '?' mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My .htaccess file looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On       
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*)-(.*) view.php?title=$1&date=$2&author=$3
```

Using this rule i am able to redirect simple dynamic url's without special characters

```
domain.com/abcd-June%2027th%202013-authorname
```

to

```
domain.com/view.php?title=abcd&date=June%2027th%202013&author=authorname
```

Similarly, I want to redirect dynamic url's containing question mark '?' in query string
for example

```
http://domain.com/abcd?-June%2027th%202013-authorname
```

to

```
http://domain.com/view.php?title=abcd?&date=June%2027th%202013&author=authorname
```

How to do this? What are the changes required in .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Use NE flag.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(.*?)/?\s
RewriteRule ^ view.php?title=%1&date=%2&author=%3 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. and no it's still giving not found error. when i remove ? mark from url it works correctly.

Comment: Is this your test URL: `/abcd?-June%2027th%202013-authorname` ?

Comment: That is what I used in my test also and it is fully working solution. Post your complete .htaccess in your question as you might have some conflicting rules.